# Rolling mean with most updated record from another column

Tags: python, group-by, python-polars, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with two datetime columns, one for the execution date ("execution_time") and another for predictions ("valid_time"). For each row, valid_time <= execution_time. And for each valid_time I may have several execution_times.

What I want to compute is a rolling mean by each execution_time such as that for every row I get the mean for the previous n hours in valid_time. BUT, when there are not enough hours in the given execution date, I want to take the missing hours from the other execution_times -taking always the highest execution_time that is smaller or equal than the one in the given row-. (I hope it gets clearer with the example)

Given this dataframe

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'execution_time': [datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6)],
 'valid_time':[datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,0),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,1),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,2),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,3),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,4),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,5),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,7),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,8),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,6),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,7),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,8),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,9),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,10),
 datetime.datetime(2023,1,1,11)], 
'value': range(16)})
```

```
     execution_time          valid_time  value
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 00:00:00      0
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 01:00:00      1
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 02:00:00      2
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 03:00:00      3
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 04:00:00      4
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 05:00:00      5
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 06:00:00      6
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 07:00:00      7
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 08:00:00      8
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 09:00:00      9
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 06:00:00     10
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 07:00:00     11
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 08:00:00     12
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 09:00:00     13
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 10:00:00     14
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 11:00:00     15
```

If I were to compute the mean with n=2, the desired result would be:

```
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 00:00:00      0        None
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 01:00:00      1   mean(1,0)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 02:00:00      2   mean(2,1)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 03:00:00      3   mean(3,2)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 04:00:00      4   mean(4,3)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 05:00:00      5   mean(5,4)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 06:00:00      6   mean(6,5)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 07:00:00      7   mean(7,6)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 08:00:00      8   mean(8,7)
2023-01-01 00:00:00 2023-01-01 09:00:00      9   mean(9,8)
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 06:00:00     10  mean(10,5)
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 07:00:00     11 mean(11,10)
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 08:00:00     12 mean(12,11)
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 09:00:00     13 mean(13,11)
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 10:00:00     14 mean(14,13)
2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 11:00:00     15 mean(15,14)
```

The important points are:

- For the execution_time 2023-01-01 00:00:00 the mean is performed taking into account rows with that execution date, but for the valid_time 2023-01-01 00:00:00 there are no 2 previous valid_times, so the return is NUll.
  For the execution_time 2023-01-01 00:00:00 and valid_times equal or bigger than 2023-01-01 00:06:00 the values are taken from this execution_time and **not** from the next one.
- For the execution_time 2023-01-01 00:06:00 the edge case is for the valid_time 2023-01-01 00:06:00. In this case, the value for computing the mean is taken from the highest previous execution_time (in this case 2023-01-01 00:00:00). For the rest of valid_times, values are taking from the execution_time 2023-01-01 00:06:00.
- Execution_date frequency is 6h, so for n bigger than 6 there are more execution_dates involved.

I have tried with rolling, rolling_mean, etc, but I can't achieve the desired result. Any ideas?

Comment: `0  mean(10,5)` <- should this not read `mean(10,6)` - or am I misunderstanding things? Also, `execution_time` is listed as both keys in the dataframe sample code.

Comment: I fixed the dataframe. As for the mean, it is correct as it is. For the execution time at 6AM The mean should have the valid time at 6AM from that execution time and the valid time at 5AM from the previous one (hence, mean(10, 5))

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to do this by looping through your unique values of `execution_time`

```
n='2h'
for i, exec_time in enumerate(df['execution_time'].unique().sort()):
    if i ==0:
        subresults = (
            df
            .filter(
                pl.col('execution_time')==exec_time
                )
            .sort('valid_time')
            .with_columns(
                values=pl.col('value').rolling('valid_time',period=n)
                )
            )
    else:
        subresults=pl.concat([
            subresults,
            df
            .filter(pl.col('execution_time')<=exec_time)
            #maybe extra filter here so not too many old results
            # something like valid_time>(exec_time-n-'1h')
            .group_by('valid_time', maintain_order=True)
            .agg(
                pl.col('execution_time').max(),
                value=pl.col('value').last()
                )
            .sort('valid_time')
            .with_columns(
                 values=pl.col('value').rolling('valid_time',period=n)
            )
            .join(subresults, on=['valid_time','execution_time'], how='anti')
        ], how='diagonal')
print(subresults
      .with_columns(
          values=pl.when(
              pl.col('values').list.len() == pl.col('values').list.len().max()
              )
          .then(pl.col('values').list.mean()))[5:13]
      )
shape: (8, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ execution_time      ┆ valid_time          ┆ value ┆ values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ f64    │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 05:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 4.5    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 6     ┆ 5.5    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 07:00:00 ┆ 7     ┆ 6.5    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 08:00:00 ┆ 8     ┆ 7.5    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ 9     ┆ 8.5    │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 10    ┆ 7.5    │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 07:00:00 ┆ 11    ┆ 10.5   │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 08:00:00 ┆ 12    ┆ 11.5   │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

What this does is in the first observed execution_time it just filters the df to just that and creates subresults using `rolling`. For each subsequent execution time, it creates a sub df of only that execution time and lower then it takes the highest execution time for each valid time and creates the same rolling values but then it does an anti join against whatever is in subresults so far so that there aren't duplicates. I'm not sure what the data looks like but you can probably add a filter to the `else` case where the `valid_time` has to be greater than the (exec_time less n less another hour) to mitigate that from blowing up too big.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm overcomplicating things.

```py
windows = (
   df.rolling(index_column="valid_time", by="execution_time", period="2h")
     .agg(pl.exclude("valid_time"))
)
```

```
shape: (16, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ execution_time      ┆ valid_time          ┆ value     │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [0]       │ # <- FIXME
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [0, 1]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 03:00:00 ┆ [2, 3]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 04:00:00 ┆ [3, 4]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 05:00:00 ┆ [4, 5]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ [5, 6]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 07:00:00 ┆ [6, 7]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 08:00:00 ┆ [7, 8]    │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ [8, 9]    │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ [10]      │ # <- FIXME
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 07:00:00 ┆ [10, 11]  │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 08:00:00 ┆ [11, 12]  │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ [12, 13]  │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ [13, 14]  │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ [14, 15]  │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

It seems like to fix each row, you need to find last row that satisfies the following condition:

```py
left.execution_time > right.execution_time 
  and left.valid_time <= right.valid_time
```

(a *"non-equi join"*)

You can sort of emulate the behaviour by using `.int_ranges()` and `.search_sorted()` (as your data is sorted)

```py
less_than = windows.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("value").list.len() == pl.col("value").list.len().min())
      .then(
         pl.int_ranges(0, pl.col("execution_time").search_sorted("execution_time", side="left"))
      )
      .alias("idx")
)
```

```
shape: (16, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ execution_time      ┆ valid_time          ┆ value     ┆ idx                            │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---                            │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]                      │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [0]       ┆ []                             │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ [0, 1]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ [1, 2]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 03:00:00 ┆ [2, 3]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 04:00:00 ┆ [3, 4]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 05:00:00 ┆ [4, 5]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ [5, 6]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 07:00:00 ┆ [6, 7]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 08:00:00 ┆ [7, 8]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ [8, 9]    ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ [10]      ┆ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 07:00:00 ┆ [10, 11]  ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 08:00:00 ┆ [11, 12]  ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ [12, 13]  ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ [13, 14]  ┆ null                           │
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ [14, 15]  ┆ null                           │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

`idx` can then be used to `.get()` the corresponding values to use in the `valid_time` comparison.

`.group_by().last()` to get only the last matching row.

```py
(less_than.explode("idx")
   .with_columns(pl.exclude("idx").get("idx").name.suffix("_lt"))
   .filter(pl.col("valid_time_lt") <= pl.col("valid_time"))
   .group_by("execution_time", "valid_time")
   .last()
)
```

```py
shape: (1, 7)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┬─────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ execution_time      ┆ valid_time          ┆ value     ┆ idx ┆ execution_time_lt   ┆ valid_time_lt       ┆ value_lt  │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ [10]      ┆ 6   ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 06:00:00 ┆ [5, 6]    │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┴─────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```